# Updating a single value for each item in object in Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list of notifications inside redux state. As you can see below. [image]

There could be more items in the list, and my goal is to set `isRead` value to `true` for all items in the list depending on the `isDiscussionType` value. I am using the following code in the reducer:

```
case MARKALLASREAD_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS:
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        notifications:
            Object.keys(state.notifications).map(id => {
                if (state.notifications[id].isDiscussionType == action.payload.isDiscussionType)
                    return { ...state.notifications[id], isRead: true }
                else
                    return { ...state.notifications[id] }
            })

    };
```

This code results in the following state, where the `key` is lost (set to 0), and the `isRead` value is not changed (although the database is updated correctly).

Do you see any problems in the code I shared above?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map returns an array instead of an object. That is why you lose your id, since the 0 is just the index within the array, which is now under notifications. I would move the generation of notifications out of the return to get more flexibility:

```
case MARKALLASREAD_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS:
    const notifications = { ...state.notifications }
    Object.values(notifications).forEach(notification => {
        if(notification.isDiscussionType === action.payload.isDiscussionType) {
           notifications[notification.id] { ...notification, isRead: true }
        }
    }
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        notifications
    };
```

This will return an immutable object with each notification changed, if the isDiscussionType are the same. Because map, filter, reduce return arrays, I would move it out of the return and use forEach.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If your `notifications` is a list i.e. an array, you shouldn't use `Object.keys` on it, and go straight with the `map`:

```
case MARKALLASREAD_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    notifications: state.notifications.map(notification => {
      if (notification.isDiscussionType === action.payload.isDiscussionType) {
        return {
          ...notification,
          isRead: true
        }
      } else {
        return notification;
      }
    })
  };
```

Comment: I think it is an object though, because why else would it start with 1 if thats not the id?

Comment: Hmm, good point. In that case OP is changing an object into array.

Comment: yes thats the problem, but I dont know yet, how to update these efficiently. If it would just be the id, it would be easy, but it is quite nested.

Comment: Thanks! Then how can I keep it as object?

Comment: See my answer above